# How to implement the template method design pattern in Kotlin?

Tags: java, design-patterns, kotlin

Consider the problem:

We have a `Base` class with an abstract method. Now, we would like to enforce that every override of this method will perform some argument checking or some other drudgery. We want this argument checking to be identical across all overrides. One solution would be to wrap this behavior in a non-abstract method which calls an abstract one:

```
abstract class Base
{
    fun computeSomething(argument: Int): Int
    {
        require(argument > 0) // Some intricate checking
        return execute(argument)
    }

    // Pure functionality, assuming correct arguments
    // Ideally, this would be private. 
    protected abstract fun execute(validArgument: Int): Int
}

class Derived1: Base()
{
    override fun execute(validArgument: Int): Int =
        validArgument * validArgument
}

class Derived2: Base()
{
    override fun execute(validArgument: Int): Int =
        validArgument * validArgument * validArgument
}


fun main(args: Array<String>)
{
    val d = Derived1()
    println(d.computeSomething(23))
}
```

I would like to have `Base::execute` private, such that no subclass of `Base` can call it by accident without checking its arguments. Unfortunately, this is not possible:

> Error:(9, 5) Kotlin: Modifier 'private' is incompatible with
>   'abstract'

Kotlin's `protected` is better than Java's `protected`, since it makes the function accessible only to subclasses but still, the ideal case would be `private`.

So is there some right way to implement this pattern? Also, just out of curiosity, is the incompatibility of `private` and `abstract` a deliberate choice of language design?

Comment: I do not know kotlin, but the error looks like computeSomething is not public.

Comment: can't you use 'protected final' ? So that it's accessible by subclasses, but cannot be overriden?

Comment: @NSimon Actually I want it to be overriden. I don't want it to be *called*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense for a function to be overridden, but not callable from that class. By overriding that function, you own its implementation, and therefore can call it.

You can accomplish what you want by detaching the execution logic from the derived classes, which can be done in a few ways:

- You could make use of a lambda, and pass that to the constructor of the `Base`
- You could create an interface implementation that handles the execution logic

By passing these to the `Base` class in its constructor, you are transferring their ownership to that class.

Comment: I agree about the lambda, that is a nice solution.

However I disagree that it doesn't make sense for a private method to be overridden. My example code illustrates that quite clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You can make them to pass object that will check the value if they would like to call this method.
example

```
abstract class Base
{
    fun computeSomething(argument: Int): Int
    {
        return execute(ValueCheck(argument))
    }

    protected abstract fun execute(validArgument: ValueCheck)

    protected class ValueCheck(a: Int)
    {
        private val value = checkValue(a)

        private fun checkValue(argument: Int): Int
        {
            require(argument > 0)
            return argument
        }

        fun get() = value
    }
}
```

and when derived class would like to call execute, it have to pass object that is checking value when creating instance